# Issue with Log files generation

Tags: bash, shell, echo, logfile

I'm having a script which does its work and used to generate a single logfile with name `Info$DATE.log.`
Now as per the new requirement I need to generate two different log files as `Info$DATE_PART1.log` and `Info$DATE_PART2.log` as given below:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
DEST='/Mydata/Test/Log'
ECHO='/bin/echo'

$ECHO " Development is in progress..." >> $DEST/Info$DATE_PART1.log
$ECHO " Testing is in progress..." >> $DEST/Info$DATE_PART2.log
```

But the problem I'm facing: there is only one logfile at destination and that only with name `Info.log` but the content (`Development is in progress...` and `Testing is in progress...`) are correctly there in `Info$DATE.log`. 
Can somebody please let me know whats wrong in above script and why this behaviour ?

Comment: Why are you using `/bin/echo` instead of the builtin echo?

Comment: Use `Info${DATE}_PART1.log` and so on.  Refer to the linked question.